# how to obtain a curve in scilab

Tags: c++, scilab

I made the following algorithm:

```
c=3e8;//m/s 
h=6.6e-34;//J*s 
lambda=200e-9;//m 
E=h*c/lambda;//J 
k0=(2*E)/(h*c);//m^-1 
l=10; 
n=1.33; 
rd=20*10^-6; 
r=1*10^-9:200:10*rd;//m 
for i=1:length(r) 
if r(i)<=rd then 
    Ep(i)=(E*(n^2-1))+(E*l*(l+1)/(k0^2*r(i).^2));//J 
elseif r>rd then 
    Ep(i)=(E*(n^2-1))+(E*l*(l+1)/(k0^2*r(i).^2)); 
end 
end 
clf 
plot2d(r,Ep,style=1);
```

I must obtain a curve and for the moment my program calculates only a value.

Comment: We need a bit more context as to what is the question, and what kind of curve and so on? Maybe some other code if relevant.

Comment: since `rd` is a single value `r` is a single value, which in turn will make your for loop only do 1 iteration and thus resulting in a single value.

Comment: well, as you can see I have the following constants : h(plank const),c(speed of light),lambda(wavelength),l(angular momentum and n(index); My equation is: Ep=E*(n^2-1)+(E*l*(l+1))/k0^2*^r2; where E=h*c/lambda(and represent incident energy), k0=2*E/h*c (and represent the wavenumber);

Comment: I have 2 cases of interest:

Comment: 1 is what hapens when r>rd (and first part of my ecuation must be 0)  and 2 when r<=rd;  sorry i forget to tell you : r is a radius of a partical, and this is my variable; and rd is radius of limit; if you know physics this is a kind of problem with barrier of potential;

Comment: How can I vary the radius to be recognized by the program? I want to have values from 0.001*10^-6 to 10*rd(200*10^-6)

Comment: how can I show you the curve that I must obtain? Sorry I started studying scilab one week ago;  I made another algorithm and I obtained two curves, which I think are good if put them together, but I dont't know how.

Comment: h=6,6*10^-34//J
l=10
n=1,33
c=3*10^8//m/s
lambda=1500*10^-9//m
E=(h*c)/lambda//eV
k0=(2*E)/(h*c)//m^-1 In micrometere-1
rd=20//micrometer
r=1*10^-5:rd;//
Ep=(E*(1-n^2)+E*l*(l+1))./(k0^2*r.^2);
r1=rd:5*rd;
Ep1=(E*l*(l+1))./(k0^2*r1.^2);
plot2d(r,log(Ep),style=5)
plot2d(r1,Ep1,style=5)
xtitle("Ep=f(r)")

Answer (score 0):

```
c=3.000D+08;
h=6.600D-34;
lambda=0.0000002;
E=h*c/lambda;
k0=(2*E)/(h*c);
l=10;
n=1.33;
rd=0.00002; 
r=1.000D-09:0.000002:10*rd;
for i=1:length(r)
    if r(i)<=rd then
        Ep(i)=(E*(n^2-1))+(E*l*(l+1)/(k0^2*r(i).^2));
    elseif r>rd then
        Ep(i)=(E*(n^2-1))+(E*l*(l+1)/(k0^2*r(i).^2));
    end
end
plot(log(r),log(Ep'));
```

This is the plot:

[image: Plot]